# Q learning and Neural Network for Tic Tac Toe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I have been working on a tic-tac-toe assignment for my Robot Learning class. We were asked to program a tic-tac-toe game and assign; +1 if X wins, -1 if O wins and 0 it the game results with a draw. In part 1, we were told to use Q table and in part 2 we were told to replace the Q table with a Neural network as the functional approximator.

It is my understanding that both methods should be achieving the optimal policy, can you confirm or deny my understanding?

Answer (score 1):

> It is my understanding that both methods should be achieving the optimal policy, can you confirm or deny my understanding?

Yes, I would expect a neural network for Q Learning to find the optimal policy, provided it remains stable*. The value estimates might be slightly inaccurate, but the resulting policy should be completely optimal. That is because in tic tac toe, all the value estimates should be -1, 0 or +1, and the data is cleanly separated.

You should be able to get a neural network to learn the optimal Q table from the first experiment using supervised learning. In fact that would be a good test of whether your NN has capacity to learn that table.

* Neural networks added naively to Q-learning agents are often not stable. In fact that is so common a problem in scaling up RL agents that it has a name: "[the deadly triad](https://davidsanwald.github.io/2016/12/11/Double-DQN-interfacing-OpenAi-Gym.html)". This is generally not solved by elegant mathematical changes to the agent, but by some engineering tricks:

- Experience replay. Save observations (S, A, R, S') and sample from this memory table later to train in mini-batches.
- Alternating networks. Use an old frozen copy of the neural network to calculate $\text{max}_{a'} Q(S',a')$ for the TD target $R + \gamma\text{max}_{a'} Q(S',a')$